# parsing python by checking database and placing

Tags: python, mysql

I have a tablename = myclass with field:student

```
**student**
 1.Jane
 2.John
 3.Maria
```

I have a text file "qwer.txt" which contains details of these student like:

```
Jane is a good student and gets good marks.
john is a naughty one.
maria is a good student.
```

I have another database table "marks" which consists of marks of these students:

```
 student english physics
 Jane     100     98 
 John     97      95
 Maria    90      91
```

Now,my program i need is I need to Search the first name of database which is "Jane" and has to search text file about Jane.it must print the line if it finds Jane then it must connect the seconds Marks database and print Jane english marks.

I did a half coding like

```
import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM myclass")


    # commit your changes
db.commit()

keywords=[]
    #here fetchall() gets all the rows and we append carnames to key words

for i in cursor.fetchall():
    keywords.append(i[0])


with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for key in keywords:
            if key in line:
               print line
```

It prints the line but missing how to connect the marks.please help

```
**MAIN OBJECTIVE**
It must search name one by one **from the table**(as input) and provide result to a text file.
It must connect another Marks database table and print marks to text file.
```

Please understand my query and help me!

Comment: so u want want corresponding results of two database and print in same table

Comment: what is i[1], here ithink its wrong since ur cursor have only one column

Comment: not in same table ,the result has to be in a new table

Comment: yes u r right only one column i will edit it

Comment: hey i have used join so that we have student and marks in single table. so no need of new connection again.

Comment: and no need to have new keyword list . since in row v fetch v have those keywords thats row[0]

Comment: but ,my main objective is to connect two different tables to a program ,do u know how to program for that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way :

```
 import MySQLdb


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT name,english,pysics FROM myclass c,marks m where c.student=m.student")


    # commit your changes




rows=cursor.fetchall() 
 db.commit()




with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for row in rows:
            if rows[0] in line:
               print rows[0],'english mark',rows[1]
```

other way:

import MySQLdb

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                         user="root", # your username
                          passwd="mysql", # your password
                          db="sakila") # name of the data base
cursor = db.cursor()

    # execute SQL select statement
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM myclass")


    # commit your changes




rows=cursor.fetchall() 
 )




with open('qwer.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for row in rows:
            if rows[0] in line:
               stmt="select english from marks where student = :student"
               cursor.execute(stmt,dict(student=row[0]))
               print "english marks:",cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```

Comment: could you make it connect for two different tables and get the data?

Comment: @user3647415 we can do that

Comment: ,i just test your code,its error like "if row[0] in line and its operand not tuple',could u help?